# Uninstall jupyter-text2code

Tags: jupyter-notebook, package, uninstallation

I started the installation of the following package https://github.com/deepklarity/jupyter-text2code , but after doing the following two commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/deepklarity/jupyter-text2code.git
cd jupyter-text2code
pip install .

git clone https://github.com/deepklarity/jupyter-text2code.git
export JUPYTER_TEXT2CODE_MODE="cpu"
cd jupyter-text2code
pip install .
```

I now want to remove it. Whenever I try to open jupyter notebook it takes forever to load and i get the following message [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7D80H.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

To uninstall the plugin, please run the following command in the terminal/console:

```
pip uninstall mopp
```

We will update the readme and update the instructions.